# How to convert stock return dataframe to a normalised index using dplyr in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a list of monthly price returns, and I want to convert them to usable prices so I can chart the time series.  I'm trying to use `dplyr`, but can't quite figure out why my solution with `cumprod` doesn't work as I expect.

Here are my price returns:

```
|  date       | MSCI_return  |
------------------------------
| 2000-12-29  |   0.000000   |
| 2001-01-31  |   0.037419   |
| 2001-02-28  |  -0.040455   |
|  ...        |   ...        |
```

Here's the dput of a shortened version:

```
prices = structure(list(date = structure(c(11320, 11353, 11381, 11411, 11442), class = "Date"), MSCI_return = c(0, 0.0374195168328921, -0.0404549887278276, 0.00126350901483074, 0.0255771959613151)), .Names = c("date", "MSCI_return"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

And here's the code which is baffling me at the moment:

```
prices %>% group_by(date) %>% summarise(price = cumprod(MSCI_return + 1))
```

Shouldn't the `cumprod` give me the accumulated product of `1 + return` values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `mutate`, not `summarise` and you don't need to `group_by(date)`:

```
prices %>%
mutate(price = cumprod(MSCI_return + 1))
        date  MSCI_return     price
1 2000-12-29  0.000000000 1.0000000
2 2001-01-31  0.037419517 1.0374195
3 2001-02-28 -0.040454989 0.9954507
4 2001-03-30  0.001263509 0.9967085
5 2001-04-30  0.025577196 1.0222015
```